# Add filters to a List<CustomObject> java

Tags: java, android, list

I have a `List<News> new ArrayList<News>();` . This list contains a SourceTitle in each list entry. There maybe multiple entries with the same SourceTitle. Now I want to  create another list which contains entries that have the same SourceTitle.

Eg. I have items like so:-

```
Id   SourceTitle  Description
1      HR            abbs
2     Company        djnj
3      HR            kjnfk
4     Extra          jfriu
5      HR            eifji
```

I want to create a list with items related to the 'HR' catagory

Here is my code:-

```
newsList = new GetList().execute(newsItems).get();

private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<News>>
    {

        private List<News> myNewsList;


        @Override
        protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONArray jObject;
            try 
            {
                jObject = new JSONArray(params[0]);
                for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++)
                {
                     JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

                     String title= menuObject.getString("Title");
                     String description= menuObject.getString("BodyText");
              String newsSourceTitle = menuObject.getString("NewsSourceTitle");



                        myList.add(new News(title, description, SourceTitle));



                }

            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return myNewsList;
        }



    }
```

Comment: You want to add HR related source in myList?

Comment: Its already there in the list. I want to filter the HR related data and add it to another list.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONArray jObject;
            try 
            {
                jObject = new JSONArray(params[0]);
                for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++)
                {
                     JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

                     String title= menuObject.getString("Title");
                     String description= menuObject.getString("BodyText");
              String newsSourceTitle = menuObject.getString("NewsSourceTitle");


                   if(title.equals("HR")){  //Put if condition only
                        myList.add(new News(title, description, SourceTitle));

                      }

                }

            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return myNewsList;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question (which isn't really clear to me) but there's a problem with the way you're using AsyncTask.  I think what you're doing causes it to run on the UI thread (which defeats the purpose).  Try this instead:

```
// ...
Callback callback = new Callback(){
      @Override
      public void done(List<News> list){
          newsList = list;
      }
};
GetList task = new GetList(callback);
task.execute(newsItems);
}

private interface Callback {
     void done(List<News> list);
}

private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<News>>
    {

        private List<News> myNewsList;
        private Callback callback;

    GetList(Callback cb){
           callback = cb;
    }    

        @Override
        protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONArray jObject;
            try 
            {
                jObject = new JSONArray(params[0]);
                for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++)
                {
                     JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

                     String title= menuObject.getString("Title");
                     String description= menuObject.getString("BodyText");
              String newsSourceTitle = menuObject.getString("NewsSourceTitle");



                        myList.add(new News(title, description, SourceTitle));



                }

            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return myNewsList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<News> list)
        {
           callback.done(list);
        }

    }
```